# sql server profiler - how to get server response?

Tags: sql, sql-server, profiler

I am investigating problem with third party application, from what I can see queries sent to sql look ok.

I am using SQL Server Profiler 2005 with Sql 2008 R2 database, I can see queries sent to database, is it possible to capture server response?

I had a look at events and columns in profiler, but I can’t see anything what would contain that data.

Thank you for help

Comment: No. You can capture information about any error messages and `rows` but not the actual data itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the network packets using Wireshark on port 1433 but the output will not be easily readable.

There is a sample on the wireshark web site, you can have a look at the contents using a text editor:
http://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=ms-sql-tds-rpc-requests.cap

It's much easier to replay the commands you see in SQL Server Profiler if possible.